# How to reset dropdown field using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I have tried below code to reset number of "adults" dropdown field on onclick of reset button but the dropdown field is not getting reset please suggest

Code for adult dropdown :

```
<select class="select_style sel_ad_{$smarty.section.sect.iteration}" id="adult[]" 
name="adult[]"
onchange="javascript:display_twin('{$smarty.section.sect.iteration}',this.value)">
<option value="0"> - </option>
{section name=adult loop=10 start=1 step=1} 
<option value="{$smarty.section.adult.index}" {if $adults_details.$sect_key eq 
 $smarty.section.adult.index}selected{/if}>{$smarty.section.adult.index} </option
 {/section} 
 </select>
```

Javascript code for reseting fields onclick of reset button :

```
 function reset_frm(){
    $("#adults_pkg").val('');
    //$("select[name='adults_pkg[0]']").val('');
 }
```

Comment: The id adult[] and adults_pkg do not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing wrong `id`.

To use existing code:

```
$('#adult\\[\\]').val('');
```

OR

Add a new class to the element:

```
<select class="pkgCls select_style sel_ad_{$smarty.section.sect.iteration}" id="adult[]" 
name="adult[]"
onchange="javascript:display_twin('{$smarty.section.sect.iteration}',this.value)">
```

And apply this:

```
$(".pkgCls").val('');
```

Comment: @pihu, then please choose my answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Default mean selected first `option` of select value, as you have have `0` value on first index so you will need to assign `0` for default index

And selector seems wrong, support the select box inside `loop` so use right selector like

```
        $(".sel_ad_{$smarty.section.sect.iteration}").val('0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$("yourSelectMenu").prop('selectedIndex',0);
```